# I'm trying to find the percentage of calories in fat but my output is never correct

Tags: java

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Calories
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    int fat;    //Grams of fat
    int fcal;   //Calories from fat
    int total;  //Number of Calories
    long result;    //Percent of calories from fat

    System.out.println("This program finds the percent of calories from fat");

    //Here the user inputs the numbers
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the total grams of fat " );

    fat = keyboard.nextInt();
    fcal = fat * 9;
    System.out.print("Enter the total number of calories " );

    total = keyboard.nextInt();
    result = fcal / total * 100;

    if(result <= 30)
    {
      System.out.println("Food is low in fat!");
    }
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0");
    System.out.println("Calories from fat : " + formatter.format(result) + "%");
    }
}
```

No matter what I input my output always comes out as zero. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm not sure whether DecimalFormat, the datatype, or keyboard.nextInt(); is part of my problem, I've gone over it multiple times and asked another person who said the code was running fine for them.

Answer (score 5):

Your `fcal` and `total` variables are both integers, so you're performing integer division. Any time `fcal < total`, you'll always get 0 as your answer.

You need to cast as a double when doing your division.

That won't quite work either since `result` is declared as `long` so there'll be a loss of precision. Either change the datatype of `result` or else cast the result back to a `long`.

Comment: double needs to be long. You get a compile error if you use a double. Just heads up man! ;-)